# Enable Health Check in a app service via CLI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, health-check

Is there any way to enable health check via cli in azure app services? I see that we can modify some configurations but not an option to enable/disable the feature.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You should add more details such as sample of your code and your execution log as it will help us help you. You can also take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it will help you understand how to properly ask a question :)

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/232191/app-service-health-check-automation.html?

Answer (score 9):

According to my test, we can enable/disable health check via changing the value of web config `healthCheckPath`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/232191/app-service-health-check-automation.html).

For example(I test it via azure cloud shell)

a. Enable

```
az webapp config set -g <groupName> -n <web name>    --generic-configurations '{"healthCheckPath": "/api/health/"}'
```

[image]
[image]

b.Disable

```
az webapp config set -g <groupName> -n <web name>    --generic-configurations '{"healthCheckPath": ""}'
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @jim-xu this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @jim-xu answer I was able to get this working for our needs.

I did struggle trying to make syntax work in an existing PowerShell script with the string quotation marks and making it a variable.  I thought I'd put that syntax here in case someone else is trying this via scripts not using `bash`.

```
# variables - these might be local or parameters from your function, etc..
$webAppName= "my-web-app"
$resourceGroupName = "my-resource-group"
$healthCheckPath = "/api/health/"

# the important part
$genericConfigurations = "{\""healthCheckPath\"": \""$healthCheckPath\""}"
az webapp config set  --name $webAppName `
                      --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
                      --generic-configurations $genericConfigurations `
                      --output none
```

Yes I did attempt to be conscientious and read through [Use Azure CLI effectively - Using quotation marks in values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?view=azure-cli-latest#using-quotation-marks-in-values) and it still wasn't clear to me.

I saw many other posts with users getting caught on this syntax; [example 1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10248#issuecomment-860034762), [example 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11978#issuecomment-613363277), [example 3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10625#issuecomment-535187531).